# AMDh264Encoder returning MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND when checking MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint

Tags: ms-media-foundation

When receiving an output from IMFTransform::ProcessOutput, calling GetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint) on the sample fails and returns MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND only while using the AMDh264Encoder (NV12 in, H264 out), as such there are no keyframes in the final output video so it is corrupted.

What causes getting attribute MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND to fail, only on the AMDh264Encoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video encoder MFTs are supplied by hardware vendors. AMD does "AMDh264Encoder" for their hardware and introduces it with their video drivers, in particular.

For this reason implementations from different vendors have slight differences, AMD guys decided to not set this attributes on produced media samples.

You should skip this gracefully and treat the attribute as optional.

Comment: Thanks, how would I determine whether a sample is a keyframe in this case then?

Comment: I am not sure if AMD encoder is exposing this, maybe you can find something [here](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/11/MediaSDK_User_Guide_1_1_Beta.pdf). Also H.264 frames are more complicated than "key frame" and "not key frame". To get more detailed information for produced data you might want to look at AMD's lower level AMF SDK. There you definitely can obtain [frame type](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF/blob/master/amf/public/include/components/VideoEncoderVCE.h#L107).

Comment: Also it's reltively easyo to parse NAL units from the produced bitstream (you'll need H.264 spec for this, or look for StackOverflow questions that expand this) and identify unit types, then detect whether it is a "key frame" or not.